# Using addbibresource after \begin{document}

Tags: biblatex

I’m using XeLaTeX, biblatex and biber to edit a journal with 10 to 15 articles per issue.

In the issue’s project folder, there is one main `journal-issue.tex` with the preamble.
Then there is a subfolder for each article with the article itself as `author-title.txt`, the article’s bibliography file as `bib-author-title.bib` and all other stuff related to it (images and such).

All the different articles are loaded using `\input{author-title.txt}`.
To keep the structure as clear and simple as possible, I would like to add the bib resource for each article within its text file, but get the error

> LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

Is there a way in which I can add the bib resources from within the article files?
I’m trying to avoid loading all of them separately in the preamble of the document.

The reason for this is that I have to edit all the articles for LaTeX and don’t want to have to make changes to the main file all the time. At the same time, I’d prefer to keep the bibliography files on a per-article-basis instead of having one long file for all articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use the command in the document body. But you can collect the needed data and write it to some file at the end of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_philipp_bibresources_tl
\NewDocumentCommand\addlocalbibresource{m}
 {
   \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_philipp_bibresources_tl
    {\exp_not:n{\addbibresource{#1}}\iow_newline:}
 }
\AtEndDocument
 {
   \iow_open:Nn\g_tmpa_iow{tmp_philipp_bibresources.tex}
   \iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow {\g_philipp_bibresources_tl}
   \iow_close:N\g_tmpa_iow
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\InputIfFileExists{tmp_philipp_bibresources.tex}{}{}

\begin{document}


\addlocalbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addlocalbibresource{test.bib}
\cite{doody}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!